# Confirmation on operator linearity ($L[y] = y''(x) + p(x)y'(x) + q(x)$)

Tags: linear-transformations, operator-theory

The book "Mathematical Physics with Partial Differential Equations" by James Kirkwood, near the end of Section 1.1 (Self-Adjoint Operators) lists as an example of a linear operator $$ L[y] = y''(x) + p(x)y'(x) + q(x).$$ I'm trying to confirm whether this is an error, with a factor of $y(x)$ missing from the last term. After expansion, I've found that the example $L[y_1 + y_2] = L[y_1] + L[y_2] - q(x)$ does not prove (disproves) the operator's property of additivity.

(On the first page of the chapter an example is given of a linear operator $\mathcal{L}[y] = a_0(x) y(x) + a_1(x) y'(x) + a_2(x) y''(x)$ which is valid, and the mistake in the later part of the chapter can be rationalized by rewriting an operator from a "pure" form: $L = \frac{d^2}{dx^2} + p(x) \frac{d}{dx} + q(x)$. I'm simply looking for confirmation of this.)

Comment: Yes, $y(x)$ is missing from the last term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are absolutely correct. It is a typo.

By definition if L = d^2/dx^2 + p(x) d/dx + q(x) then

L[y] = y" + p(x) y' + q(x) y